# Android Firebase Database: Selecting father of subtree

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database structure:

[image: dbstructure]

I have the following code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("tsdzskLGyVZvgflaKDhfntHpB443");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OnDataChange");
                if ( dataSnapshot.exists() ){
                    Log.d(TAG, "travelname add: " +dataSnapshot.getValue() );    
                }
            }
```

which produces the following output:

```
D/SelectFriendTravAct:OnDataChange
D/SelectFriendTravAct: travelname add: {testTravel={-KkbcQmUhnKoVUGLBpgn=692ffda5-b197-44a8-bda7-5f0f6d8db14c.png, -KkavGiyImQylckuwzvv=a901d768-e9c0-47f0-a683-346bb8a88e47.png}}
```

Instead i need only to retrieve the root of subtree: "testTravel". Is there a way to get only that without downloading the entire subtree?

Answer (score 0):

Getting value upto n levels is not possible in realtime database. However if you are using it only for quick UI build, use REST api. Also it won't eat up your concurrent connections.

Try:

```
https://database_url/tsdzskLGyVZvgflaKDhfntHpB443.json?shallow=true
```

Note: You need to grant public read access or use access tokens. Read [more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth)

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work.  i still have the subtree........ travelname add: {testTravel={-KkbcQmUhnKoVUGLBpgn=692ffda5-b197-44a8-bda7-5f0f6d8db14c.png, -KkavGiyImQylckuwzvv=a901d768-e9c0-47f0-a683-346bb8a88e47.png}}

Comment: @QuasarLex not possible with realtime database. use rest database

Comment: @PriyeshKumar Your comment is correct and you top/updated answer does show how to accomplish the result with the REST API. Please remove your original code, since it doesn't solve the question and keeps this from being a correct answer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addValueEventListener with a for loop and pass the name of the subtree you want to use.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                for (DataSnapshot child :dataSnapshot.child("testTravel").getChildren())
                {



                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });
```

Comment: The problem is that "testTravel" is the name i would like to know, so i can't use it as a constant string. I don't need to use any part of the subtree